# eclipse press F2 for focus popping up different window

Tags: python, eclipse, ide

I want to be able to view the documentation for any given function in Eclipse (for Python), similar to pressing Ctrl-Q on IntelliJ.

I know that when I hover my mouse over a function, it will show a short peek of that function (tooltip). The window that appears also says "Press F2 for focus."

It sounds like F2 is what I want. However, when I press F2 (after having the tooltip pop up on any function), I get another window instead, which doesn't even have a title, so I don't know what its purpose is.

[Window which appears when I press F2; asks something about the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cp55.png)

When I click OK, it opens the console, which is not what I want. Rather, I wanted only to see the documentation.

I also checked in File, Edit, Refactoring, etc. and found no option to view the documentation of a function.

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set focus on the tooltip when pressing **F2** because PyDev is binding that key to the command **Execute line in console**, which was the unnamed window shown in your screen shot. You can confirm this by selecting **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys**:

[image: F2binding]

You could bind that command to a different key so that **F2** reverted to doing what you expected (*Show Tooltip Description*), but there is no real need because there is a simple alternative for setting focus: just click on the tooltip with the mouse and it will get focus:

[image: PythonTooltip]

However, if you still want to be able to use **F2** to set focus on tooltips in Python just change the binding for **Execute line in console** to some alternative unused value. In  the screen shot below I changed it to **Alt-F2**:

[image: RemapF2]

After doing that:

- Pressing **F2** will set focus on the tooltip.
- Pressing **Alt-F2** will open the unnamed window allowing you to execute a command in the console.